# multiple SQL commands in one RTT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that I can enter multiple statements on a single line. Just end each one with a semicolon, like this:

```
mysql --host 127.0.0.1 -u root 'SELECT VERSION(); SELECT NOW()'
```

I am curious in my above example, how many round trips is paid? Does mysql use pipeline to wrap these two statements in one network packet and send them altogether? Or it sends the first statement and then waits for the reply?

Comment: Seems like the sort of thing you could easily answer for yourself if you have some kind of packet analyser software (e.g. wireshark or network monitor).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I realized that after I posted this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'm here to answer my own question. I watched it from wireshark. The short answer is it sends each command in each RTT.